# Is linking to autocomplete results possible?

Tags: ajax

When users search a member profile using Views autocomplete exposed filter text field, is it possible to link the result values? Suppose we are searching some 'XY' user. The results appear as autocomplete drop-down. When we click on them, we are redirected to the member's description page.

Is linking to autocomplete results possible?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, not it is not possible. The drop-down list is created dynamically basing on the user input; there isn't a page that shows you that drop-down list content in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
You can try [Search Autocomplete](https://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) moodule.

Module page says:

```
 This module allows you to add autocomplete functionality to virtually any fields of a Drupal site. During the input, the field will be expanded and offer a list of suggestions before you start the search.
    By default, the module integrates with search forms from the Drupal core Search and Search Block.

Uses either static data, external or internal URL callback or an embeded view style to easily create your suggestions set.
```

For more information go through the module documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Is there any video tutorial how to use this search autocomplete module.